# Неправильно работает таймер WinForms

Tags: winforms, таймер

Я разрабатываю симулятор роста растений. Для каждого растения предусмотрено конкретное кол-во стадий и длительность одной стадии. Для прохождения по нескольким стадиям использую цикл for, в котором вызываю метод с таймером, где он описывается и запускается. Также, прописаны timer.Tick и Timer.Stop. Проблема состоит в том, что вместо того, чтобы включаться и тикать на каждой стадии роста (то есть при каждом вызове метода в цикле), он включается и тикает только на последней. Причем, во всех остальных стадиях проходит все строки метода, кроме Tick. И, таким образом, нарушается вся цепочка действий. *Как это выглядит:*

Инициализация массива растений выполнена
Инициализация массива картинок выполнена
Таймер запущен
Стадия 0 пройдена
Таймер запущен
Стадия 1 пройдена
Таймер запущен
Стадия 2 пройдена
Растение Подсолнух выросло
Время 5
Время 4
Время 3
Время 2
Время 1
Время 0
Стадия пройдена

Ниже цикл, включающий в себя стадии роста растения.
Plants.masPlants[0].CountSteps - кол-во стадий для этого растения.
PlantGrowth - метод. Проверяет и определяет пройденные и не пройденные стадии растения. Возвращает  текущую стадию/если стадия последняя -число 13.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Plants.masPlants[0].CountSteps; i++)
        {
            TimerStart(timer0, label_time0, textBox1);
            var plantgrowstep = Plants.PlantGrowth(Plants.masPlants[0], i, textBox1);
            PlantPicture.Image = new Bitmap(images[i]);
            if (plantgrowstep==13)
            {
                textBox1.Text += $"Растение {Plants.masPlants[0].NamePlant} выросло\r\n";
                //MessageBox.Show($"Растение {Plants.masPlants[0].NamePlant} выросло");
            }
        }
```

Метод таймера. Уже использовался в другом проекте. Работал, только там он не вызывался в цикле.

```
static int tk, p;

    static string c;
    public static void TimerStart(Timer timer, Label label, TextBox textBox)
    {
        p = 5;
        c = "00:05";
        label.Text = c;
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Start();
        textBox.Text += $"Таймер запущен\r\n";
        timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
        {
            textBox.Text += $"Время {p}\r\n";
            tk = --p;
            TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(tk);
            string label_time = span.ToString("hh':'mm");
            label.Text = label.ToString();
            if (p < 0)
            {
                timer.Stop();
                textBox.Text += $"Стадия пройдена\r\n";
            }
        };
    }
```

метод PlantGrowth:
[] plant.GrowSteps - булевой массив для обозначения пройденных стадий.

```
public static int PlantGrowth(Plants plant, int i, TextBox textBox)
    {
        plant.GrowSteps[i] = true;
        if (plant.GrowSteps[plant.CountSteps-1]==true)//если последняя стадия роста прошла
        {
            plant.IsPlantGrown = true;
            textBox.Text += $"Стадия {i} пройдена\r\n";
            return 13;
        }
        textBox.Text += $"Стадия {i} пройдена\r\n";
        return i;
    }
```

Я новичок, не судите строго.

Answer (score 0):

все правильно.

Вы в цикле запускаете ОДИН И ТОТ ЖЕ таймер.

Не успевает этот таймер что то сделать - как уже происходит следующая итерация цикла, и вы опять запускаете тот же самый таймер.

Если Вы хотите непременнно использовать таймер - нужно поменять архитектуру приложения, примерно так:

оставить один таймер, а уже в нём (точнее, в методе обработки события Tick) - запускать цикл по всем растениям.

Таким образом, у Вас на каждый тик таймера будет происходить симуляция одного шага роста всей популяции растений.